# Поблочная прокрутка с разделением страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

я не лентяй, правда искал, но не нашел (
как реализовать поблочную прокрутку с разделением страницы?
на примере - https://wellexpo.select-themes.com/design-conference/

Comment: А это и не прокрутка вовсе. Можно сделать `body { overflow: hidden; }` и сделать обычный вертикальный слайдер, который будет срабатывать при нажатии стрелок `document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){ if( e.key == "ArrowUp" ){ /*...*/ } else if ( e.key == "ArrowDown" ) { /*...*/ } })`

Comment: Возможно, эта библиотека поможет http://bit.ly/2k7NvXg

Answer (score 0):

Да действительно, это не скроллинг fullpage, а слайдер.

codepen.io/oliviale/pen/WJoqNZ - по клику

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js - по скроллу